# how to user rowspan colspan in bootstrapTable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, helper

I use bootrapTable to create the table. how can i use rowspan or colspan to create a table like this:
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbdTE.png)

```
 $table.bootstrapTable({
                  columns: [{
                      formatter: 'rowIndex',
                      title: "No",
                  }, {
                      field: 'company',
                      title: 'test1',
                      sortable: true,
                  }, {
                      field: 'sum_employee',
                      title: 'test2',
                      sortable: true
                  }]
                });
```

Comment: https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#column-options/rowspan-colspan.html

Comment: thank you. but how can i use it in above create command. i tried with colspan and rowspan but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here : https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#data
The span has be specified inside the data object loaded by bootstrapTable

**You might consider giving more details as i have to imagine what's the use of the empty cell here.**

Anyway, this will result in an object like this one :

```
   $table.bootstrapTable({
      data: [{
         id: 1,
         No: 1,
         _No_rowspan: 2,
         name: 'Test 1'
      },
      {
         id: 2,
         No: 1,
         _No_rowspan: 2,
         name: 'Test 2'
      }]
   })
```

Comment: thank you. but but i want to create them with header column.